# Setting multiple allowedUnits for NSDateComponenstFormatter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponentsformatter

### Background:

When formatting an NSTimeInterval using an NSDateComponentsFormatter, it's often handy to use the `allowedUnits` property to round the resulting string to a relevant time unit.

For example, I may not be interested in getting time to the second, so setting the `allowedUnits` to minutes gets an appropriately rounded output string:

```
let duration: NSTimeInterval = 3665.0    // 1 hour, 1 minute and 5 seconds
let durationFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()

durationFormatter.unitsStyle = .Full
durationFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .DropAll
durationFormatter.allowedUnits = .Minute

let formattedDuration = durationFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(duration)
```

`formattedDuration` will be "61 Minutes".

### The problem:

How would you go about setting `allowedUnits` to `.Hour` and `.Minute` so the formatted duration would be "1 hour, 1 minute" instead?

The [NSDateComponentFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015130-CH1-SW13) doesn't really cover how to do this.

Comment: durationFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by Leo, you can simply provide the `allowedUnits` in an array like so:

```
durationFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute]
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution I've come up with is to create a `NSCalendarUnit` by adding the raw values of the desired allowed units together:

```
durationFormatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: NSCalendarUnit.Hour.rawValue + NSCalendarUnit.Minute.rawValue)
```

I't be interested to know if there's a better syntax or alternative way to do this.

Comment: durationFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute]

Comment: durationFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 2

Comment: Cheers Leo, your first suggestion worked perfectly. I didn't realise that you could just provide the units in an array like that.

Comment: You can add all of them and limit UnitCount to 2

Comment: You will use this syntax a lot with Swift 2.0